# Handling inputs for int, char, float

Tags: c, input, scanf

I am trying to write a program that loops asking the user to continuously input either a float, int, or char and echo it back to them until they enter 'q', then the loop ends. I do not understand how to decipher between an int, char, or float before entering the loop. I have tried if (scanf("%c", ch)) and so on for float and int and that works great, but once I added the loop in it's messing me up. I have tried several different combinations, but I have still not found my answer.
Here is one attempt to show you exactly what I am trying to do:

```
    char ch;
    int num = 0;
    float fl = 0;

    printf("Enter a value: ");
        while(ch != 'q') {
            if (scanf("%c", &ch) && !isdigit(ch)) {
                printf("You entered a character %c\n", ch);
            }
            else if (scanf("%d", &num)) }
                printf("You entered an integer %d\n", num);
            }
            else if (scanf("%d", &num)) {
                printf("You entered a floating point number %f\n", fl);
            }
        printf("Enter another value: ");
      }
   }
```

This keeps doing something strange and I cannot pinpoint my problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `else if (scanf("%d", &num)) {
                printf("You entered a floating point number %f\n", fl);
            }` makes no sense. Did you mean `else if (scanf("%f", &fl)) {
                printf("You entered a floating point number %f\n", fl);
            }`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot accomplish that with your approach. You can scan a line and parse it accordingly:

```
char line[128]; /* Create a buffer to store the line */

char ch = 0;
int num;
float fl; /* Variables to store data in */

int r;
size_t n; /* For checking from `sscanf` */

/* A `do...while` loop is best for your case */
do {
  printf("Enter a value: ");

  if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) /* If scanning a line failed */
  {
    fputs("`fgets` failed", stderr);
    exit(1); /* Exits the program with a return value `1`; Requires `stdlib.h` */
  }

  line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0'; /* Replace `\n` with `'\0'` */

  r = sscanf(buffer, "%d%zn", &num, &n);
  if(r == 1 && n == strlen(line)) { /* If true, entered data is an integer; `strlen` requires `string.h` */
    printf("You entered an integer %d\n", num);
  }
  else{
    r = sscanf(buffer, "%f%zn", &fl, &n);
    if(r == 1 && n == strlen(line)) { /* If true, entered data is a float; `strlen` requires `string.h` */
      printf("You entered a floating point number %f\n", fl);
    }
    else{
      if(strlen(line) == 1) /* If true, entered data is a character; `strlen` requires `string.h` */
      {
        ch = line[0];
        printf("You entered a character %c\n", ch);
      }
      else{ /* Entered data is something else */
        printf("You entered \"%s\"\n", line);
      }
    }
  }
}while(c != 'q');
```

Disclaimer: I wrote the above code using a mobile and I haven't tested it.

---

Update *(did not test and wrote with my mobile)*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{

    int c = 0;

    bool random = false;
    bool flag = true;
    bool is_float = false, is_char = false, is_number = false;

    do{
      c = getchar();

      if(c == EOF)
        break;

      if(!random)
      {
        if(isdigit(c))
        {
          is_number = true;
        }
        else if(c == '.')
        {
          if(is_number)
          {
            if(is_float)
            {
              random = true; 
            }
            else
            {
              is_float = true;
            }
          }
          else if(!is_number && !is_float && !is_char)
          {
            is_float = true;
          }
        }
        else if(c == '-' && !is_float && !is_number && !is_char);
        else if(isalpha(c))
        {
          if(is_char)
            random = true;
          else
          {
            is_char = true;
            if(c == 'q')
              flag = false;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          random = true;
        }

        if((is_char && is_float) || (is_char && is_number))
          random = true;

        if(c == '\n' && !is_char && !is_float && !is_number)
          random = true;
      }

      if(c == '\n')
      {
        if(random)
          /* puts("You entered a random string!"); */
          puts("Invalid input!");
        else if(is_float)
          puts("You entered a float!");
        else if(is_number)
          puts("You entered a number!");
        else if(is_char)
          puts("You entered a character!");
        else
          puts("Error!");

        if(!flag && !is_number && !is_float && !random)
          flag = false;
        else
          flag = true;

        is_char = is_float = is_number = random = false;
      }
    }while(flag);

    puts("Done");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I am not allowed to use a string or array. I know it's not recommended to post homework questions on here, but it is the fact that I have been attempting it for days now and I don't know if there is another approach to scanning in int, chars, and floats and echoing them back. That's my issue. I've read some places mentioning using the ascii table to accomplish this, but I don't know if that would be too complex of a stab.

Comment: You should've mentioned that requirement in your question. Unfortunately,  I think that it is impossible to check if user input is a character, a float, a number or something invalid *and* print the character/float/number without arrays and strings. I've written some code in my answer although I haven't tested it as I'm using my phone and won't be using my laptop for some days. You can fiddle around with the code I've written. Note that the code requires `ctype.h`(For `isdigit`, `isalpha` etc) and `stdbool.h`(For `bool`, `true`, `false` etc) (`stdbool.h` is available only in C99 and above).